# Is US English the only language with mmddyyyy format?

Tags: internationalization, date

Are there any other languages that default to anything other than ddmmyyyy (other than the US)?

I'm working on an international project and wondering if there are any other languages that use the mmddyyyy date format. I have a limited knowledge of many languages but so far it seems most use ddmmyyyy instead.

Comment: If you're working in .NET (for example) you can use it's built in `CultureInfo` class to get this sort of information for you.

Comment: I personally prefer yyyymmdd for it's obvious sorting properties. I can confirm Australia uses ddmmyyy

Comment: Canadians depending on location will use ddmmyyyy or mmddyyyy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are even more variations. Check Wikipedia:

[**List of the world locations by date format in use**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#List_of_the_world_locations_by_date_format_in_use)

Comment: Belize, Palau, and Micronesia (besides the US and Canada) - yup, the big players - all of them! :-)

Comment: Excellent x-ref.  And it seems that only countries with a strong US influence use the mm/dd/yyyy notation.

Answer (score 5):

This may be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date